# How to write apps in xcode 6.1 to run in iPhone 4s or earlier

Tags: ios, architecture, compatibility, xcode6.1

I am working on Xcode 6.1 and built an application that runs perfectly on iPhone 5s and later simulators. More information on the application:

- The app uses a static library(with 64 bit architecture).
- Base SDK: iOS 8.1
- Deployment target: 8.1

Now, when I try to run the app on iPhone 5 or iPhone 4s (or earlier) simulators, it fails to build with Apple Mach-O Linker errors and warning. I guess it might be compiled in 32 bit architecture to solve this. But should I even change the architecture of the library (which is in my scope)? If so, how can that be done? I tried many times by changing the architectures of both the app and library to 32 bit but failed.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your static library needs to be built for both 32 and 64 bit just as your app is. 64 bit only existed in the 2013 released devices.

Comment: Ok i get it, so that it is supported by both older and new versions of iPhones right? Also can you please explain as how can I achieve that? @ahwulf

Comment: Assuming you are building the library yourself with a project or target, just enable both 32 and 64 bit in the build configuration. If you are getting this library from somewhere else you will need to get them to do this. Just like applications static libraries can be built with support for multiple architectures.